# DataTable do not get updates?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a `DataTable` with one column filled with list of words from a text file, I create a method to read a string if the string is founded the row must be deleted, but the problem is that the `DataTable` don't get the updates.

```
foreach(string line in file)
{
   tagst.Rows.Add(line)
}

string s;
for (int k = 0; k < tagst.Rows.Count; k++)
{
   s = tagst.Rows[k]["Tags"].ToString();
   if(s.Equals("Jad"))
   {
      tagst.Rows[k].Delete();
   }
}
```

Comment: `words` doesn't seem to be used.  You would also have to iterate backwards to delete a row since once you delete one, your index is off.

Answer (score 0):

after your loop, call `tagst.AcceptChanges();`

per the documentation:

`When AcceptChanges is called, any DataRow object still in edit mode successfully ends its edits. The DataRowState also changes: all Added and Modified rows become Unchanged, and Deleted rows are removed.`

As @LarsTech stated, you'll want to rework your loop like:

```
for (int i = tagst.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    // ....
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but when I have to rework or iterate backward my loop?

Comment: Your index would be off, and you'd miss rows.  But I don't think you need to actually as your changes aren't applied yet.

Answer (score 0):

One issue with your coding is that when you removing rows - you need to start from the last one backward for very simple reason. Once you remove row 3,10,20 out of 100 how many rows will remain? Why do you need to start from bottom? Because **tagst** will be automatically re-indexed and reordered as soon as delete completed.

But your **tagst.Rows.Count** is already set and not getting refreshed ever!

Basically once your counter(K) hit number where rows already been deleted you will see error at best, at worse your app will crush if you do not have error handling routines set. Since you did not post actual code for how you create your tgst I will show how it can be done in array. Declaration of variable ommited...
Try this:

```
 for (int k=tagstArray.Count; k>0; k--)
   {
       s = tagstArray[k].ToString();
       if(s.Contains("Jad"))
        {
           tagstArray[k].Remove(k);
        }
    }
```